# Valid SSH command to create a RAID5?

Tags: command-line, mdadm, raid5

Valid SSH Commands for creating and rebuilding RAID5 with 4 drives:

To create a RAID5 with 4 hard drives:

mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/hd[abcd]5

To rebuild a RAID5 with 4 hard drives:

mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2

Comment: The data will be gone, but you will have a Raid 5...

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do (e.g., create a *new, blank* array, or repair an existing one), and why `mdadm --assemble` doesn't work.

Comment: @davidbaumann the use of `--assume-clean` shouldn't result in any data being overwritten other than the RAID configuration.

Comment: BTW, yes this may be a valid command to rebuild a RAID5 volume.  No idea if it is the write command to re-build your volume, which I am guessing you are trying to recover.

Comment: @derobert, I am being trained to rebuild RAID5 arrays via SSH as an advanced technical support agent. I was told the above command is what should be used to do this, but I question it because the last time I used it, the RAID did not rebuild. I am looking for a better command. I think my instructor is missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're trying to rebuild as in restore redundancy to an array that has lost one disk

1. If the array is not already assembled, assemble it: `mdadm --assemble --scan /dev/md1` (if it's in the config file) or `mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2`. If one of the disks has failed, just leave it off the line.
2. If the rebuild was needed because because of an unclean shutdown, etc. it should happen automatically now. You can watch the status by `cat /proc/mdstat`. NOTE: If it says its in 'auto read-only mode', you need to write the the array (mounting the filesystem surely will), or use `mdadm -w /dev/md1` to get it to start.
3. If the rebuild is because of a failed disk, add the replacement disk to the array: `mdadm -a /dev/md1 /dev/sde2` (`sde2` being the new disk). You might have to do `mdadm --run /dev/md1` as well.

If by "rebuild" you mean recover from something that is supposed to be fatal to RAID5 (e.g., double-disk failure), then that's more complicated, and the steps depend on exactly what lead up to the failure.

Comment: "If the rebuild is because of a failed disk, add the replacement disk to the array: mdadm -a /dev/md1 /dev/sde2 (sde2 being the new disk). You might have to do mdadm --run /dev/md1 as well." Can that last command be added to the former? something like :mdadm --run -a /dev/md1 /dev/sde2

Comment: @damata I don't think you can add it to the `-a`... you'd add it to the `--assemble` instead. I'm not sure if its required (and didn't feel like setting up a VM to test).

Comment: @damata I will add, though, that you probably should set up VMs to play with—they're a great way to learn how the stuff works.

Comment: Though I am a tech support agent, my IT dept doesn't believe in allowing us to install VM's to our workstations to test. I would do that if I could. I need 2 lines of code, one for rebuilding a RAID5  with 1 failed drive, one for creating a new RAID5 with 4 drives. I may also need some help with rebuilding a 2 disk RAID1 and have no help from the "Advanced Support".

Comment: @damata `--create` is how you create a new (blank) one (though please don't use `--assume-clean`). `--assemble` is how you put together an existing array. `-a` is how you add a new disk to an array—if the array has all the disks it should, it will add a hot spare; if not, it'll use the new disk to rebuild a degraded array. Hopefully you can at least review the mdadm man page? Also, sounds may want to ask [workplace.se] how get your manager(s) to authorize training and/or experimentation.

Comment: So, the process would be: mdadm -a /dev/md1 /dev/sde2 to add the replacement device to the RAID, then : mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sde2 to assemble the RAID with the failed device out of the line and the replacement device in?

Comment: What does --assume -clean ) do in the content of mdadm? I couldn't find any references to them in the Man pages?

Comment: @damata odd, it's in my copy of the manpage. Anyway, it tells it to skip the initial sync. Normally when you create an array, it starts off by initializing the parity. Passing that flag tells it to assume it's already there.

Comment: maybe I was looking at the wrong Man Pages. Would you be so kind as to point me to what you use please? Thanks for the Workplace link, but IT is not budging and my supervisor is not willing to push the issue for me. He HAS admin rights on his workstation though.

Comment: @damata you should get it if you type `man mdadm` but here is an online copy: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm

Answer (score -1):

No; --create means exactly what it says: create a new array.  Replacing the failed drive with `mdadm --add` should automatically start the rebuild.

Comment: See the docs for the `--assume-clean` option, which the OP included in the command.  http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm The command has a chance of being valid, if what he uses has the options exactly indentical to the command that orignally created the array with the same drive order, chunk size and so on.

Comment: @Zoredache, rebuild means replace a failed drive, not blow away and recreate the array.  The latter is very dangerous and often leads to tears.  It should only be used if you really know what you are doing, and only then as a last resort.  More often, people misuse it when they really want something else and trash their data.